# assistance with specific command in Bash

Tags: command

i have a proggram written in c like that

```
argv[0]=command;
argv[1]=NULL;

if(strcmp(command,"ls > try.txt")) {
     dup2(fd,1);
     close(fd);
     execvp(command,argv);
     perror("execvp");
     exit(1);
}
execvp(command,argv);
perror("execvp");
exit(1);
```

I want: if i write ls >try.txt only this command work

Comment: Try enclosing the command in quotation marks, like this: `./a.out 'ls > try.txt'`

Comment: the problem is that if i text in Bash ls it doesnt show me the output. I want if i text ls>try.txt then put the outputs into the try.txt only in that case and if i text any other command just to show me it outputs have any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand that :-(